# The points $(0, k),(0,-k),(k, 0)$, and $(-k, 0)$, where $k \neq 0$, comprise the vertices of a square. Why is the side-length not $2k$?

Tags: geometry, area

The points $(0, k),(0,-k),(k, 0)$, and $(-k, 0)$, where $k \neq 0$, comprise the vertices of a square. What is the area of the square?

1.$\frac{k^{2}}{2}$
2.$\frac{k^{2}}{\sqrt{2}}$
3.$k^{2}$
4.$2 k^{2}$
5. $4 k^{2}$

I thought this square centered on the origin has side-length 2k, so the area is $4k^2$. The answer is $2k^2 \implies$ The side-length must be $\sqrt{2}k$.
It turns out we have a diamond centered on the origin also.

**Why is the side-length not $2k$?**

Comment: Draw a picture! The square in question is exactly that diamond...

Comment: The question is ambiguous. given four points, there are more than one interpretation of how to draw the lines. depending on how much you want to maximize the area.

Comment: No. There is only one square that has exactly those four points for vertices.

Comment: (not every quadrilateral is a square...)

Comment: The square is not the way you are imagining it (with sides parallel to the co-ordinate axes). Instead, it is tilted/rotated (around the origin) by $45^\circ$, and, from that perspective, even though it is still a square, it looks more like a diamond. Its one side is connecting the points $(k,0)$ on the $x$-axis with the point $(0,k)$ on the $y$-axis and its length can be calculated via Pythagoras' theorem to be $\sqrt{2}k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Trivial answer.** We have a square $\rightarrow$ it has $4$ sides having equal (Euclidean) length. Then, by Pythagorean Theorem, the length of one side is given by $\sqrt{(k-0)^2+(k-0)^2}=\sqrt{2(k-0)^2}=\sqrt{2 \cdot k^2}=\sqrt{2} \cdot k$. Q.E.D.

P.S.
I have no idea if this kind of questions fits the aim of MSE or not.

Comment: How do you know the origin and $(k,k)$is on the boundary of the square? @Marco

Comment: You have to just draw the $4$ points on the Cartesian coordinate system, the shape is a square whose diagonals cross in the center $C \equiv (0,0)$.

Comment: (k,k) is not on the boundary @BoredStar. Neither is (0,0).

Answer (score 1):

First, what is the error you're making? Well, I tend to doubt that you've actually drawn a picture of the square you have in mind, with the vertices carefully labelled. From what you're saying it seems you think that the segment from $(-k,0)$ to $(k,0)$ is a side of the square. But no, draw the picture! That segment is a side of two different squares, but those squares do not have vertices $(0,\pm k)$. In fact the segment from $(-k,0)$ to $(k,0)$ is a *diagonal* of the square, as is clear from the looking at the picture, which is possible once the picture exists. (Or maybe you were thinking of the segment from $(0,-k)$ to $(0,k)$; that's also a diagonal, not a side.)

A cute way of resolving this without knowing what the picture looks like:

> > **Def.** The "distances determined by the four points $A,B,C,D$" are the six distances $d(A,B)$, $d(A,C)$, $d(A,D)$, $d(B,C)$, $d(B,D)$, and $d(C,D)$.

> > **Cute Fact.** If $A,B,C,D$ are vertices of a square then the length of a side is the smallest of the six distances determined by $A,B,C,D$ and the length of a diagonal is the largest.

For the four points in the problem, four of the distances are $\sqrt 2k$ and two are $2k$. So $\sqrt 2k$ must be the side length.